Sum of Optimized Parameters Matches Initial Guess Sum in Autograd_Minimize
I'm encountering an unexpected behavior while using the autograd_minimize function in Python for optimization. Here's a summary of the issue:
Objective: I'm using autograd_minimize to minimize an objecttive function. The objective function computes the error between calculated values and expected values based on input parameters.
Observation: After running the optimization process, I've noticed that while the individual optimized parameters  are different from the initial guess parameters, the sum of the optimized parameters is matching the sum of the initial guess parameters. This behavior is unexpected as I don't have any constraints that enforce such a match.
Expected Outcome: I would expect the optimization process to converge to parameter values that minimize the error, without necessarily matching the sum of the initial guess parameters.
I've reviewed the implementation of the objective function (objective_torch) and the optimization setup, but I haven't been able to identify the source of this unexpected behavior.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with autograd_minimize or have any insights into what might be causing the sum of the optimized parameters to match the sum of the initial guess parameters? Any suggestions or advice on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance!
I have tried all methods in the framework and it seems that it behaves only in methods with gradient computation.
